# Is this a valid set property block?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a setter in a property a bit like this:

```
set
{
string whatever = regex.replace();

_fieldStub = whatever;

}
```

As you can see, there is no use of the value keyword. Is this still a perfectly valid set block?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just compile and test for yourself, also, why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this still a perfectly valid set block?

Yes, it technically is a valid property setter.  There is nothing which *requires* you to use the value passed in.

However, this property will likely be highly unusual, and violate all expected behavior.  As such, I would recommend making this a method instead.

Answer (score 0):

it compiles? 
 
if it does - it's valid 
if not - it's not valid. 
 in validation of code the last word belongs to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It's valid for the compiler but it does not have meaning in .Net language scope. It behaves like a method, not .Net property

```
public string MyProperty
{
  set
  {
   string whatever = regex.replace();

   _fieldStub = whatever;

  }
}
```

This won't have any effect on my property

```
myClass.MyProperty = "Hello"; //has no effect and makes no sense
```